# Help import scipy

Tags: python-2.7, ssh-import-id

I need help with scipy of Python 2.7 please

```
oscar@COM0324:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
>>> 
>>> 
oscar@COM0324:~$ sudo apt-get install python-scipy
[sudo] password for oscar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-scipy is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate

oscar@COM0324:~$
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Did you enable the `universe` repository?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/python-scipy  it is in universe. Do you have that active?

Comment: Try installing scipy from the Ubuntu Software Center. The reason for using the Software Center is that there are two python-scipy packages: python-scipy and python-scipy:i386 and this will let you choose the package that matches your operating system's architecture.

Comment: go here down load and extract:https://github.com/scipy/scipy/archive/master.zip cd in extracted dir. then do $python setup.py install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have "Universe" enabled? See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/148645/16395

In my Ubuntu 14.04 is all ok installing `python-scipy`:

```
[romano:~] % apt-cache policy python-scipy
python-scipy:
  Installed: 0.13.3-1build1
  Candidate: 0.13.3-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 0.13.3-1build1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```